# Doob Decomposition for non-negative supermatingale

Tags: convergence-divergence, martingales

Show that for a non-negative supermartingale $M$ with $\lim_{n \to \infty}E[M_n] = 0$ we have $\lim_{n \to \infty}M_n = 0$ almost surely and the Doob decomposition is reduced to $M_n = E[A_\infty|\mathscr{F}_n]-A_n$ where $A_n$ is a non-decreasing, predictable sequence.

For the first part, I said that since we have a non-negative supermartingale then we know that the limit exists almost surely where $E[M_\infty|\mathscr{F}_n] \le M_n$ $\forall n$, and therefore:
$$
0 \le E[M_\infty] \le \lim_{n \to \infty}E[M_n] = 0 
$$
and since this supermartingale is non-negative if $E[M_\infty] = 0 \Rightarrow M_\infty = 0 \; a.s$.

For the second part, it's Doob decomposition is $M_n = X_n - A_n$ where $X_n$ is a martingale. Therefore, the goal is to show $X_n = E[A_\infty|\mathscr{F}_n]$.

I said that $\lim_{n \to \infty}M_n = \lim_{n \to \infty}X_n - \lim_{n \to \infty}A_n$ which implies $X_\infty = A_\infty$ almost surely. Now in order for $X_n = E[X_\infty|\mathscr{F}_n]$ I believe we need to show that either $(X_n)_{n \ge 0}$ converges in $L_1$ or is uniformly integrable.  However, unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out why that's true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close: $(M_n)$ converges to $0$ in $L^1$.  So does $(A_n)$, because it's a non-negative  increasing process with $E[A_n]$ bounded above by $E[X_0]$. Consequently, $X_n=M_n+A_n$ also converges in $L^1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please explain how we know that $E[A_n]$ is bounded above by $E[X_0]?$ If a process is increasing with its expected value bounded - then we know it converges in $L^1?$

Comment: Because $A_n=X_n-M_n$, so $E[A_n] = E[X_n]-E[M_n]=E[X_0]-E[M_n]\le E[X_0]-E[M_0]\le E[X_0]$. (Used here: $(X_n)$ is a martingale while $(M_n)$ is a non-negative supermartingale.)